# Copy driver transform object when creating new scene

Tags: drivers, scene

Is there a way either when copying a scene or even and easy way after, to update the "transform object" of a driver? I've noticed that even if creating a new scene as "full copy" that although all the objects and meshes are properly duplicated, that the driver object of the newly created key is still set to the original driver object. I know I can simply change it in the graph editor, but in some cases scenes can have many meshes with many keys and this becomes quite tedious.

See in this outliner image, I've duplicated the scene with "Full Copy" and although all my objects are now single user, both keys are using the same Driver Object.

[image: driver object in outliner]

[image: driver object in graph]

Answer (score 1):

I would submit that as a bug. I would expect a new driver if I did a full scene copy, and not have a Scene 1 object still driving a Scene 2 target.

Comment: Well, I found this [similar bug][blender] already reported, but they closed it as "not a bug." However, in my case I'm copying full scene so the mesh is not duplicated so should it not update the driver references to the new objects as well?  

 [blender]:https://developer.blender.org/T32552

Comment: Where's the old bug report?